# What is synchronized and how?

Tags: windows-10

Sometimes, when I reinstalled Windows 8.1, I got back to my start screen layout, desktop backgrounds and some other settings, like Visual Studio settings.

This stopped to work in one of Windows 10 test builds, and now seems to work again, but I'm not sure. There is a full release, so (theoretically) it should work. My all preferences should be synchronized with the cloud. But are they?

What exact settings are synchronized? Edge bookmarks? It's very important; if Edge bookmarks are not synchronized, then it's a waste of time to create bookmark knowledge base now in Edge. Are there any conditions for synchronization? Let's say I make a clean install of Windows 10, with option "keep nothing".

Let's say something broke in my user profile; so, I detach my profile from Microsoft Account, fix the profile and then reattach the profile to local account again. Last time I've done this was to rename my user profile folder. I've noticed all my settings gone.

The point is that I've done the same in Windows 8.1 (converted my profile to local account and then again to Microsoft account); my settings stayed.

Comment: Most of this is clearly documented.  I am not sure how to answer the how portion of your question please clarify it.  I know installed Universal Applications will not be synced, I know your start menu configuration will not be synced, the rest of what will be synced is in the options to enable/disable as you see fit.

Comment: I really hope that humanity has not come down to building knowledge bases out of bookmarks in a web browser.

Comment: You are right in that not everything is synchronized. Your desktop background will be synchronized, and your personalization settings such as menu colors. I have also noticed that some settings in certain system utilities appear to be synchronized. Among the things that are not synchronized that I miss the most (since Windows 8) is the layout of my tiles, icons, and group names. It would seem obvious to me that this is something that should have been implemented right from the start in Windows 8, or at very least in Windows 10.

Comment: I advise you to create one user account and one user profile per computer user, and you stick to it. In other words stop changing it back and forth, i.e. "detach" and "reattach" user profile to and from local account or Microsoft (cloud) account. If you do this often enough, you will undoubtedly end up with a broken user profile, or profiles. If you have made a mess already, you can start over by deleting any associated synchronization data for the device. You do that in your Microsoft account settings on the web, I believe it's hidden away somewhere on the OneDrive page.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Theme, web browser settings including bookmarks, and passwords and other important settings are synchronized. 
[image]

Check out this link for more info.
https://www.howtogeek.com/222110/understanding-the-new-sync-settings-in-windows-10/

Comment: First of all, Welcome to Super User!  We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but please do not provide answers that are only a hyperlink.  While the information may be valuable, if the source web page ever goes offline the answer is essentially useless.  Quote all of the pertinent excerpts from the article within your answer, then you can still provide the hyperlink to cite your source.  Please see the following article from our Help Center:  [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: OK. I was unknown to this things.

Comment: That is understandable.  Please edit your answer accordingly.