# Acer touchpad and windows10

Tags: windows-10

I have an Acer Aspire 5560G and have updated to Windows 10. My problem is that the scroll section of the touch pad doesn't work. The mouse wheel works OK.

Comment: Have you made sure that the touchpad drivers are installed and if yes, if they are compatible with Windows 10. check manufacturer site too.

Comment: I think so, but maybe not compatible with Windows 10 maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this steps? Bcoz this steps fixed my issue with TouchPad. https://www.cnet.com/how-to/fixing-windows-10-touchpad-problems/

Comment: Please edit this answer to include the pertinent information here, as noted in Run5k's comments on your [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1195293/461558)